# How to know if an IntegerLiteral comes from a decimal or octal representation with Clang?

Tags: c++, c, clang

As you may know, integer values in `Clang` library are handled by [IntegerLiteral class](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1IntegerLiteral.html).

But, as a matter of act, there seem to be no difference between these two assignments :

```
int i,j;
// i is assigned 42 with octal representation (052)
i = 052; 
//j is assigned 42 with decimal representation (42)
j = 42;
```

AST-dump yields the same tree :

```
|-DeclStmt 0x1cbc5b0 <line:2:2, col:9>
| |-VarDecl 0x1cbc4d0 <col:2, col:6> i 'int'
| `-VarDecl 0x1cbc540 <col:2, col:8> j 'int'
|-BinaryOperator 0x1cbc610 <line:4:2, col:6> 'int' lvalue '='
| |-DeclRefExpr 0x1cbc5c8 <col:2> 'int' lvalue Var 0x1cbc4d0 'i' 'int'
| `-IntegerLiteral 0x1cbc5f0 <col:6> 'int' 42
|-BinaryOperator 0x1cbc680 <line:5:2, col:6> 'int' lvalue '='
| |-DeclRefExpr 0x1cbc638 <col:2> 'int' lvalue Var 0x1cbc540 'j' 'int'
| `-IntegerLiteral 0x1cbc660 <col:6> 'int' 42
```

I'd like to throw some warning because using octal representation can dangerously be misunderstood. Can I distinguish the way these two representations are parsed by Clang ?

Comment: Looks like you must needs hook into the parsing itself, before it's put into an `IntegerLiteral` instance.

Comment: It's going to be difficult, I fear, since I'm acting through another application (OClint).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After not being able to implement the answer given by **Richard Smith** I found quite a  nasty way to do it (and It won't work with MACROS), but in case, here is my (incomplete yet functional) solution :

```
bool VisitIntegerLiteral(IntegerLiteral * intLiteral){
    // Source Location of current int literal
    SourceLocation loc = intLiteral->getLocation();
    // Source manager associated
    SourceManager &SM = _carrier->getSourceManager();
    // Get first char and second char of the integer literal (getCharacterData returns the whole code from the SourceLocation until the end of code)
    char first_char = SM.getCharacterData(loc,nullptr)[0];
    char second_char= SM.getCharacterData(loc,nullptr)[1];
    // If first character is 0
    if(first_char == '0'){
        // If second character is also a number
        if(second_char == '1' || second_char == '2' || second_char == '3' || second_char == '4' || second_char == '5' || second_char == '6' || second_char == '7' || second_char == '8' || second_char == '9'){
            cout << "This is an octal value" << endl;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: This will do the wrong thing in some cases (for instance, if the literal is formed by a token paste or contains an escaped newline).

Comment: As I'm just looking at the first character and the second of the IntegerLiteral, I doubt that there I could be an escaped newline in the very beginning.

Answer (score 2):

Call `clang::Lexer::getSpelling`, passing it the `SourceLocation` of your `IntegerLiteral`. You can then do a manual test for octal or whatever other spelling properties you're interested in (look for a leading `'0'` followed by a digit, for instance). Performing this check manually will also let you get some special cases right -- for instance, `0` is technically an *octal-literal*, but you probably don't want to treat it that way.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I can't find  a way to get all the parameters for a `getSpelling` call. I can get the location of the current `IntegerLiteral` and the corresponding `SourceManager`, but after a lot of tries, I have not found any way to properly get a SmallVectorImpl<char>...

Comment: @Marc-O Once you have the source location you can just read the line from the file, can't you?

Comment: Yes, that's what I did (look at my answer). But the char * returned contains the whole code, and not just my integerLiteral

Comment: @Marc-O Declare a variable of type `SmallVector<char, 16>`, and pass that in.

Answer (score 0):

If the integer constant is given in octal or decimal way, it's only a syntactical fact. After compiling, the integer literal is converted to the same binary number. In the case of positive numbers the representation is precisely stated by the standards, being the exact binary representation of the integer value being stored.

So, in any case, the information about the radix in the source program (octal, decimal, hexadecimal) is not stored anywhere, hence it's not possible to know anything about it in the execution environment.

I agree with the **Deduplicator**'s comment: you need to preprocess the source code itself to "see" this information.

Another alternative could be that you do not use `int` values in a first approach, but strings instead.

```
  char *s_val1 = "052";  
  char *s_val2 = "42";  
  if (radix(s_val1) == 8)   // You can write some function radix() to recognize the radix
      printf("%s is octal", s_val1);

  int val1 = octalstr_to_int(s_val1);  // You can write some string-to-integer convertion functions
```

Comment: Well I can't use strings since I'm parsing other programmers code. I have to make sure they do not use octal values. And with `Clang` I have no choice but to use `IntegerLiteral` to check the given value